# mvn deploy failed for publish an app to exchange

Tags: xml, maven, anypoint-studio, mulesoft

I am trying to publish an asset to exchange using maven. But when I executing the `mvn deploy` getting an error as `sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

**POM.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>86771b6c-3ac1-49a4-9cb6-9930fdfd3e4b</groupId>
<artifactId>hello-world-publish-deploy</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>mule-application</packaging>

<name>hello-world-publish-deploy</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

    <app.runtime>4.2.1</app.runtime>
    <mule.maven.plugin.version>3.2.7</mule.maven.plugin.version>
    <type>app</type>
</properties>
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>Repository</id>
        <name>Corporate Repository</name>
        <url>https://maven.anypoint.mulesoft.com/api/v1/organizations/${groupId}/maven</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.maven.plugin.version}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <cloudHubDeployment>
                    <muleVersion>4.2.1</muleVersion>
                    <username>*****</username>
                    <password>*****</password>
                    <environment>Sandbox</environment>
                    <applicationName>hello-world-publish-deploy</applicationName>
                    <workers>1</workers>
                    <workerType>Micro</workerType>
                </cloudHubDeployment>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-http-connector</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
        <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-sockets-connector</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.5</version>
        <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-apikit-module</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.6</version>
        <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
      <repository>
        <id>anypoint-exchange</id>
        <name>Anypoint Exchange</name>
        <url>https://maven.anypoint.mulesoft.com/api/v1/maven</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
        <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name>
        <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>Repository</id>
      <name>Corporate Repository</name>
      <url>https://maven.anypoint.mulesoft.com/api/v2/organizations/${groupId}/maven</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
        <name>mulesoft release repository</name>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

**settings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 
      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
   <servers>
     <server>
       <id>Repository</id>
       <username>lalithponnusamy</username>
       <password>xxxxxx</password>
     </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

commands I have tried are:

1. mvn deploy
2. mvn clean package deploy
3. mvn deploy - 
   DaltDeploymentRepository=publish::default::https://maven.anypoint.mulesoft.com/api/v1/organizations/86771b6c-3ac1-49a4-9cb6-9930fdfd3e4b/maven

**Error:**
[image]

Please help me git rid of this.

Comment: You should change your password urgently.

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that Java doesn't recognize the public certificate of the host `maven.anypoint.mulesoft.com`. That usually means that either your Java installation doesn't have an up to date list of known Certificate Authorities, or that some security device in your corporate network is replacing certificates 'transparently', causing the certificate validation in Java to fail.

If you can enable Java SSL debug log for Maven you could see the certificate list is updated, or if the remote certificate is being replaced. I could not find a way to do it though. Capturing traffic with Wireshare would at least allow to find if the certificate is being replaced.